# Python SciKitLearn and Pandas categoric data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on multivariable regression from a csv, predicting crop performance based on multiple factors. Some of my columns are numerical and meaningful. Others are numerical and categorical, or strings and categorical (for instance, crop variety, or plot code or whatever.) How do I teach Python to use them? I've found One Hot Encoder (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) but don't really understand how to apply it here.

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')

df.drop(df[df['LabeledDataColumn'].isnull()].index.tolist(),inplace=True)

scale = StandardScaler()

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
X = df[['inputColumn1', 'inputColumn2', ...,'inputColumn20']]
y = df['LabeledDataColumn']

X[['inputColumn1', 'inputColumn2', ...,'inputColumn20']] = scale.fit_transform(X[['inputColumn1', 'inputColumn2', ...,'inputColumn20']].as_matrix())

#print (X)

est = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

est.summary()
```

Comment: For you categorical data, you should try scikit learn's label encoder (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: @KevinK. thanks! How would I apply it to this example, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Create a new label encoder `le = LabelEncoder()`, fit it to your data `le.fit(df['SomeColumn'])` and transform your data `df['SomeColumn'] = le.transform(df['SomeColumn'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the get_dummies function pandas provides and convert the categorical values.

Something like this..

```
predictor = pd.concat([data.get(['numerical_column_1','numerical_column_2','label']),
                           pd.get_dummies(data['categorical_column1'], prefix='Categorical_col1'),
                           pd.get_dummies(data['categorical_column2'], prefix='categorical_col2'),
                          axis=1)
```

then you could get the outcome/label column by doing

```
outcome = predictor['label']
del predictor['label']
```

Then call the model on the data doing

```
est = sm.OLS(outcome, predictor).fit()
```

Comment: What about something like this?
`

pd.factorize(df.featureX)

transformed_featureX = pd.factorize(df.featureX)

df['transformed_featureX'] = transformed_featureX[0].astype(float) # or whatever could be int as well
`

Comment: Well..get_dummies() is much easier. Give it a try and let me know and please upvote if you think it worked.

Comment: It's throwing an error: 

  File "<ipython-input-23-47bd02486cec>", line 13
    axis=1])
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I could try to debug it if you could paste some sample data in your question